# How to parse second level JSON Array

Tags: android, json, parsing

I am following [this](http://androidarms.blogspot.in/2014/06/json-parsing.html) tutorial to parse JSON Data

and now i know how to parse simple JSON with single JSON Array, but now i have to parse multilevel JSON

like i am able to parse 1st Level list but don't know how to parse second level, see my JSON Format below:

```
{
            "batches": [
                {
                    "title": "Beginners",
                    "students": [
                        {
                            "name": "Jack"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Lam"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Temp"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Intermediate",
                    "students": [
                        {
                            "name": "Ashta"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Advance",
                    "students": [
                        {
                            "name": "Kamak"
                        },
            {
                            "name": "Basi"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

My first level JSON Parsing result like this:

> Beginners
>
> Intermediate
>
> Advance

now i want whenever user do tap on **Beginners** need to list their records:

> Jack
>
> Lam
>
> Temp

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArrayBatches, jsonArrayStudents;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    ListView listView;
    ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    static String NODE_BATCH_TITLE = "title";
    static String NODE_STUDENT_NAME = "name";
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
        // execute AsyncTask
        new JSONData().execute();
    }
    
    private class JSONData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();           
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            progressDialog.setTitle("JSON Parsing");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();
            Log.d("onPreExecute()::", "onPreExecute()");
        }
        
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("doInBackground()::", "doInBackground()");
            // initializing ArrayList
            arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            
            jsonObject = JSONParsing.getJSONfromURL("URL");
            try {
                
                // locate the array name in JSON
                jsonArrayBatches = jsonObject.getJSONArray("batches");
                // using for loop to get the length of json array
                for (int b = 0; b < jsonArrayBatches.length(); b++) {
                    // get the each and every json object from array
                    jsonObject = jsonArrayBatches.getJSONObject(b);
                    // name,value pair
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMapBatches = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // put data into HashMap & convert json object to string
                    hashMapBatches.put("title", jsonObject.getString("title")); // node name = name (in JSON)                   
                    // add HashMap to ArrayList
                    arrayList.add(hashMapBatches); 
                }
                // locate the array name in JSON
                jsonArrayStudents = jsonObject.getJSONArray("students");
                // using for loop to get the length of json array
                for (int b = 0; b < jsonArrayBatches.length(); b++) {
                    // get the each and every json object from array
                    jsonObject = jsonArrayBatches.getJSONObject(b);
                    // name,value pair
                    HashMap<String, String> hashMapBatches = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // put data into HashMap & convert json object to string
                    hashMapBatches.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name")); // node name = name (in JSON)                 
                }
            
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args)
        {
            // reference to ListView
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // put ArrayList to Adapter
            listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
            // set Adapter to ListView
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("onPostExecute()::", "onPostExecute()");
            
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, arrayList.get(position).get(MainActivity.NODE_STUDENT_NAME), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity.java:-**

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_main);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use GSON that will be far more easy and faster than developing this sort of logic..

Comment: here it the link https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Comment: After first level, you have to make one loop of "batches" json array size, inside that you need to do same process again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello You Can check here and follow the solution and proper way to handling JSON..

1.[MainActivity](http://pastebin.com/LX1KYVwe)

2.[SecondActivity](http://pastebin.com/vvW9LHhv)

3.[FirstListAdapter](http://pastebin.com/GbZ6PFvD)

4.[SecondListAdapter](http://pastebin.com/Rc1Zufft)

You can understand full JSON Parsing here..

Comment: such a easy way ! i think the best way, we can get this work to done thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This...

```
//first level 
jsonArrayBatches = jsonObject.getJSONArray("batches");
        // using for loop to get the length of json array
        for (int b = 0; b < jsonArrayBatches.length(); b++) {
            // get the each and every json object from array
            jsonObject = jsonArrayBatches.getJSONObject(b);
            // name,value pair
            HashMap<String, String> hashMapBatches = new HashMap<String, String>();
            // put data into HashMap & convert json object to string
            // hashMapBatches.put("title", jsonObject.getString("title"));

                    //Second level 
                JSONArray json_second = new JSONArray("students");
                for (int i=0;i<json_second.length();i++)
                {
                     JSONObject jsonObject = json_second.getJSONObject(i);
                     String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                             hashMapBatches.put("name", name);
                }
           }
```

Comment: By Adding this code to your current code you could get second level Array which is "students"

Comment: yes i got it, but i have written code in MainActivity.java and have to parse tapped list item using Intent, and don't know what to write in SecondActivity.java !!

Comment: she must have to search it...its not gonna work here

Comment: @DevCarlsberg i want a way to get my work done, if you will see above i have written whole code and i don't have time to waste

Comment: @Prag's actually i am working on solution which you provided me and will let you know OK

Comment: sonali better to come  in chat and ask your doubt's.

Comment: ya sure..i'm ok with that

Comment: thanks i ticked it as useful but be frank using pankaj sharma's code because i can understand this more powerfully, anyways thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ready made answer first you have to understand JSON using this link.

[JSON LINK](http://json.org/). Because you have to understand exactly what you want to do with JSON.
and

to verify your JSON and Identify which is JSON String, JSON Array, JSON Object i suggest you to use

[JSON Formate](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/), here you have to pass your JSON data or use live URL and check which one is Array, Object and String.